# How to work out sqft/m of land coverage?

Tags: qgis, land-cover, land-use

I am currently self teaching myself on qgis whilst volenteering on a project on a river catchment and your help is hugely appreciated!

I need to be able to work out the percentage of land cover or sqft/m coverage. I have all the land uses on as a vector layer over my river catchment.

Many thanks and let me know what other info i need to give as a newbie!

Comment: What exact result are you looking for? Do you just need the polygon area values?

Comment: I think he first need to make a union or clip with his polygons (land uses and river catchment area). Then he can move on as described in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Group Stats plugin. I've described it's usage in http://anitagraser.com/2013/02/02/group-stats-tutorial/.

You can put the land use class in rows, the "sum" operator in columns and "area" in value to calculate the sum of all areas per land use class.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, the group stats worked a treat and I have actually taught the professional I am working for something. Taking it to the next level, Is there a way I could select a section of my land use map and work out the % within that area? sorry to sound like a real noob, thats because I am at the moment!

Comment: @stevemaloney Great it worked for you. If you have a follow-up question, please open a new thread so everyone can see it.